# WCF Config: Setting maxReceivedMessageSize for all bindings?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

Currently I am setting the **maxReceivedMessageSize** on each binding, is there a way to simply set it for all at once?

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IQQQService" maxReceivedMessageSize="250000"  />
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ISSSService" maxReceivedMessageSize="250000"  />
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IDDDService" maxReceivedMessageSize="250000"  />
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IFFFService" maxReceivedMessageSize="250000"  />
  .....
```

Comment: I suggest it is not possible as the main purpose of different bindings with different settings will be lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not supply a name it should be treated as the default.

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="250000">
</wsHttpBinding>
```

This is for WCF4, more information can be found [here on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx).